# Retrieve a changed variable from a map/reduce task in hadoop

Tags: hadoop, global-variables

I have a global boolean variable that controls a loop in the main function to determine whether or not to start over.  The decision is made in a reduce where the variable is set to true if a condition is met. Then in the main, if the condition is met it runs the entire program again. This works on one machine but when I try to run it on Amazons EC2 it does not loop through.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that on EC2 you run in a really distributed mode (multiple machines, each running its own JVM) while on your machine you run in standalone mode (where only 1 JVM is used).

When you run the job on your machine, the hadoop framework runs the client (the so called driver), the map task and the reduce task in the same JVM. Consequently, your reduce function and main will be able to work with the SAME global variable. (As a side note, I think this global variable should be static since the hadoop framework might create multiple objects for the client, map, reduce execution. If you didn't make it static and it still works on your machine it means it uses the same object).

When you run the job on EC2, you will have the client, the map task and the reduce task running in different JVMs. Consequently, the reducer will modify the "global" variable of the object residing in the current JVM, so the JVM running the client (having it's own version of the global variable in an object residing in its JVM) won't see the modifications made by the reducer to the "global" variable.

Note the quotes around global. They denote the fact that the variable is not as global as you expect it to be.

You can pass the variable from the reducer back to the driver(main class) either by writing the value of that variable in a file and place that file in the distributed cache or by writing the value of the variable in the output of the job (part-r-xxxx files) in case you can separate it from the actual  output/payload.

In both cases the driver would be able to either retrieve the file from the cache or the output files from the output directory of the job. Read in the value(s) of the variable and, based on that, take a decision.

In case you want to count how many reducer reached a particular state. You can use a user defined Counter(which will be incremented by each reducer when reaching that state) and you can interpret it in the mapper. The counter can be accessed by its name using getCounter() method of the Mapper.Context/Reducer.Context

Comment: The variable is static, I understand why its not working but I need to know how to fix it. I have been reading about Zoo Keeper but have not seen how I can implement it in this situation. Also I have read the possibility of using a distributed cache... Would it be possible to set a "hold" on the jobs to not terminate each node until all are finished? Again though I do not think it would hold the flag the way I intend it to. Also I have been considering that if the conditions are met then create a file then if the file exists loop through.

Comment: I want this to scale well with large data sets if I write it to one of the output files I would have to scan through all of them in order to see if a line is different from the rest. I am having trouble understanding the distributed cache and how to implement it have you worked with it in the past? Counters will not work I think because I do not know how many edges will be dropped.

Comment: A distributed cache is exactly what it name says. You put things into it and you can retrieve them from some other place: 
URI fileUri = new URI(uri);
DistributedCache.addCacheFile(fileUri, conf);
DistributedCache.createSymlink(conf);

Comment: Ok that sounds like what I need thanks for the help I'm going to try that when I get to work tomorrow. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have a global variable in your map reduce job as Razvan mentioned because your code is running on many machines (distributed) all in parallel.  A reduce job on server A is (and must be for MapReduce) completely independent of code running on machine B.  You'll have to wait for the job to finish (successfully or not) before you restart.  If you can wait to finish, you can set a variable in your configuration or use a counter to server as your 'global variable' and reference it when the job has stopped.  If you're using HBase, you can set a value in HBase and read it job completion as well if you want.

Your situation might make HBase a bit overkill unless you already have it set up.

To set a configuration, do the following in your main driver function:

```
conf.set("variableName",variableValue);
```

To access the configuration in a Mapper or Reducer:

```
Configuration conf = context.getConfiguration();
String variableValue = conf.get("variableName");
```

Please note that each mapper or reducer will be blind to any changes in that are made to a variable by another mapper or reducer.  I'm not sure if you even want to modify the conf variable within a mapper or reducers- it may not be best practice.

For a counter, you can do the following in your mapper or reducer (increments counter by 1):

```
context.getCounter("counterName").increment(new Long(1));
```

When your MR job is done, you can reference the counter in the following way:

```
Counters counters = job.getCounters();
Counter counter = counters.findCounter("counterName");
long cntVal = counter.getValue();
```

Again, you only can trust your counter values once your MR job is completed and not while the MR job is running.

Comment: Hi, could you elaborate on setting a variable in configuration? I am using the JobConf method. Also how would a counter work in this situation? I am working with graph algorithms and this one in particular is supposed to set a flag if an edge is dropped. If the flag is true then re run the program. I will look into HBase for the time being.

Comment: I do not know how many edges will be dropped as the reducer runs. Is there a way to retrieve data from the reducer to the main?

Comment: you need your reducer to output some sort of unique record that it has 'hit an edge' or come across some specific scenario.  You can do this by writing something to hdfs or to hbase.  you'd probably want this output to be unique per reducer per job.  Once you launch the job, poll for the output from your reducer(s) or for the job to complete.  If you receive output that you've 'hit an edge', you can kill the job and handle it accordingly.  Ultimately, however, it seems you may want to restructure your MR job as you don't want to launch a new job in the fashion you're describing...

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing this with counters its not as pretty but it works. I created two variables cnt and cnt1. I used a counter to increment if the condition was met. cnt holds the count from the last time the job was looped cnt1 is updated after the job, if they are the same then It doesn't loop through again.  This ends up running all of the jobs one extra time but it gives the correct output.

Thanks for the help.